# How to cache for multi server environment? Memcached, Redis or other?

Tags: plugins, cache

Am researching ways to speed a a multiserver wordpress install. In the past there was plugins like batcache that used memcache to store objects. That plugin is outdated and wanted to know in 2018 what is the best way to store objects in memory for Wordpress.

My goal is to speed up our wordpress site and take load off servers while caching objects( limiting DB interaction) without using page caching if possible (in memory solutions).

Answer (score 0):

The combination of NGINX, Varnish Cache, Memcached, & Redis is recommended for the best WordPress CMS hosting performance on a web server for high traffic websites. The load balancer is determinant in a multi-server environment, i.e. using AWS, Kubernetes, Docker, CoreOS, Mesosphere, etc. for orchestration. The best multi-server caching solution for WordPress is a CDN, where for example CloudFlare has over 150 data center locations.

Comment: yes we use LBs in front of nginx with cloudflare.  What I'm thinking after looking through Cloudflare instructions it may be overkill for us... we just need a simple shared boject caching (memcache) to store objects and possibly whole pages for users not logged in.  If it was a single server env. I would enable page caching to disk and be done with it...